# R Shiny - loading icon while SQL query populates selectInput

Tags: r, shiny

I have seen using the `shinycssloaders` package how loading icons can be used in conjunction with outputs (i.e., `plotOutput`). I have a Shiny module similar to this pseduocode:

```
super_module_server <- function(id) {
    moduleServer(
      id,
      function(input, output, sesion) {
          data <- sql_query()
          selected <- mod_selectInput_server(data)
      })
}
```

In this code, `sql_query()` retrieves data from a remote database and returns it as a tibble. It is passed to `mod_selectInput_server` which uses that data to populate a standard `selectInput`.

Is there anyway to demonstrate to the user that the SQL query is running (like a spinning icon) rather than just leaving an empty dropdown list until the data populates?

Comment: You can also try `shinycustomloader`

Answer (score 0):

Sure, we can add a spinning loading icon alongside our dropdown.

Find a small loading gif that you like and place it in your apps www folder.

The below minimal example shows how we can use shinyjs to show and hide our loading gif.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
    #Allow our app to use shinyjs
    useShinyjs(),
    
    #Our dropdown
    selectInput("mydropdown", "Dynamic Dropdown", choices = "Nothing Here Yet"),
    
    #An action button to populate our dropdown, simulating a long running SQL query
    actionButton("myactionbutton", "Populate Dropdown"),
    
    #Our loading icon, made hidden by default
    hidden(img(id = 'icon_loading', src = 'loading.gif'))
    
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
    #Runs when myactionbutton is clicked
    observeEvent(input$myactionbutton, {
        
        #Show our loading icon
        shinyjs::show(id = 'icon_loading')
        
        #Sleep for 5 seconds to simulate long running SQL query
        Sys.sleep(5)
        
        #Update dropdown
        updateSelectInput(session, "mydropdown", choices = runif(5))
        
        #Hide our loading icon
        shinyjs::hide(id = 'icon_loading')
        
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```